# Exception handling review

Tags: c#, exception

Im wondering whether im handling exceptions correctly in my code so was hoping someone would give me some thoughts on my code below

```
 public IEnumerable<Job> GetAll() {
        try {
            return this._context.Jobs;
        } catch (SqlException ex) {
            //error so dispose of context
            this.Dispose();
            //wrap and rethrow back to caller
            throw new CentralRepositoryException("Error getting all jobs", ex);
        }

    }
```

this method is part of my business logic and calls the method above

```
    public IEnumerable<Job> GetAllJobs() {
        try {
            return this._jobsRepository.GetAll();
        } catch (CentralRepositoryException ex) {
            //logging code to go here
            //throw back to caller
            throw;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this._jobsRepository.Dispose();
            //logging code to go here
            //throw simple exception to caller
            throw new CentralRepositoryException("A general exception has occurred");
        }
    }
```

my custom exception

```
public class CentralRepositoryException : System.Exception {
    public CentralRepositoryException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) {
    }

    public CentralRepositoryException(string message){
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a code review question!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with this approach:

- Returning `IEnumerable<T>` will cause delayed execution of the code. Even if you return `IEnumerable<T>`, in the code use `this._jobsRepository.GetAll().ToList();`
- Delayed execution causes the error handler not to be called at all since the code will be running delayed and in the client context (i.e. wherever you are using it)
- Wrap all your `IDisposable` objects in a `using` block

So an alternative would be:

```
public IEnumerable<Job> GetAllJobs() {
    try {
        using(var jobsRepository = new JobsRepository()) // !!! Use Dependency Injection, etc
        {
              return jobsRepository .GetAll().ToList(); // !! NOTE: ToList() avoids delayed execution

        }
    } catch (CentralRepositoryException ex) {
        //logging code to go here
        //throw back to caller
        throw;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //logging code to go here
        //throw simple exception to caller
        throw new CentralRepositoryException("A general exception has occurred", ex); // !!!!!! INCLUDE THE ORIGINAL ERROR !!!!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh ok.  Wrapping in the using block disposes of them automatically.  i forgot about that

Comment: actually thinking about it i dont want to dispose after every call as this destrys the context.  Hence why i was doing it only if there is a exception

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't simply re-throw an exception as you loose the stack trace.  I can see you're using them to dispose of the objects, this should be in a [finally block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Unless you can *truly handle* an exception you shouldn't be using a catch, as you *want* it to bubble up the call stack so that it can be fixed - rather than hidden.

Comment: He uses throw; which preserves the call stack.

Comment: @m.edmondson the reason im disposing of the objects in the catch clause is so that if there isnt an exception objects im disposing are still available.  Any ideas?

Comment: @m.edmondson im catching both exception and centralrepositoryexception

Comment: @PVitt - Only if you use the singular 'throw' but he's making a `new` object.

Comment: which he is using at least in one catch block.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct use of Dispose().  If you notice you end up writing:

```
this.Dispose(); 
this._jobsRepository.Dispose();
```

Both of these are refering to the same object.  To ensure that you only dispose once, it is the reposability of the class declaring the IDisposable to call dispose.

This means that if you create a local variable, you do so in a using statement:

```
using(SomethingDisposable foo = new SomethingDisposable())
{
    //...
}
```

or explictly dispose:

```
SomethingDisposable foo = new SomethingDisposable();
try
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
}
```

If you create a field you make your class disposable too:

```
class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private SomethingDisposable foo = new SomethingDisposable();

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        foo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you treat you IDisposables in this way then your exception handling won't get confussed with your disposing.